# Google Spreadsheet Query count based on column header

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
Name 8/13/2020 | 8/17/2020 | 8/20/2020
John    OT          OT          OT
Bob     OT          AL          OT
Echo    A           LE          OT
```

I would like to enter in one cell a date and then have it output me how many people have "OT", "AL", or "LE" in their column. As such I thought about using the query to do this:

```
=QUERY(MySheet!B:P, "SELECT COUNT(D) WHERE D = 'OT' OR D = 'AL' OR D = 'LE' LABEL COUNT(D) ''")
```

However, I always have to specify the column on which it has to count, is there a way I can not specify count and instead have it match up the correct column based on a date I enter in another field?

If you know of a different way I can do this that does not uses query, that is fine too as an answer.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/146781/256097 use column headers in your google sheets query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(6,         MATCH(B2, 5:5, 0))&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH(B2, 5:5, 0))), "OT")
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A6:A, INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(6,         MATCH(B2, 5:5, 0))&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH(B2, 5:5, 0)))})
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A6:A, INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(6,         MATCH(B2, 5:5, 0))&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH(B2, 5:5, 0)))}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  pivot Col2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to be able to get this to work. I am looking at your first approach as that is what I'm looking for, a total number vs each person.  What does number 6 represent? I see the 5, 5 is skip 5 rows and use next 5 rows.

Comment: see the 3rd formula

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TtTW7iDZiQ_9FVA6VqeN6-uVJW9WgwLr7vETZed7jZU/edit#gid=2034708239

Comment: Third formula splits people up, basically what those letters stand for is On Time, Absent, Arrived Late, Left Early. I just need to know how many people are there, whether they arrived  late or left early or are on time does not matters.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: Sure, result shows what I wish to see when i select said date based on the data spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gt2s4qwyoalUloKieSkCQObIIyJ0Uvf1H6rp8CqqH64/edit?usp=sharing